# Erase content of stolen phone, but thief has my PIN

Tags: security, lost-phone, data

My phone was stolen.

I tried to erase it but the only option was set up erase. The problem is I believe the person that has my phone also has my PIN which would give them access to the phone. I know the setup erase and erase are two different things but I'm not sure how they each function. I would like to erase the content so once they are in the phone there is nothing to see because I have a lot of sensitive information on it. If the information is revealed, it would be damaging. The phone is a TCL A2X.

Is this possible, or am I screwed?

Comment: https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager